# Automatic username generation

Tags: users, 8

How do I create a user registration form where username field cannot be modified by the user and is auto-generated on the basis of two other fields in form (dynamically).

I know there are some modules available for the task in Drupal 7, but how do I achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: as there is no such module available for drupal 8. You need to create your own module..

Comment: as I asked in the question. How do I do that? How would I create the pattern? I have no clue where to start.

Comment: There is a D8 DEV (caveat emptor) version of [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) which would cover your query quite well.

Comment: I tried that @macjules, but it's not the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Create your module, then create a form "MyRegForm" where the user can input her email and (if needed) password (twice with the '#type' => 'password_confirm'). Then, in the submit() method create your user like this:

```
\Drupal\user\Entity\User::create([
            'name' => 'hGzfT54re39OpLLLk',
            'pass' => 'hGzfT54re39OpLLLk',
            'mail' => $data->mail,
            'status' => 1,
            'init' => $data->mail,
            'created' => time(),
            'changed' => time(),
            'login' => 0,
            'access' => 0,
        ])->save();
```

The change the username and add whatever roles you need with code like

```
    $tuser = user_load_by_name('hGzfT54re39OpLLLk');
    $tuser->setUsername('My super name logic');
    $tuser->addRole("whatever");
    $tuser->save();
    $rc = $tuser->id();
```

If you don't want to create your own form for registration, go for hook_form_alter and set the #access to the "name" field to false and add a #default_value.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you when I'm done :D

Comment: At first it showed errors but I fixed it with correcting my initial logic. Thanks @Rainer :D